# How can I set up the Origin Store version of Command & Conquer: Generals to run a full HD?

Tags: origin, command-and-conquer-generals

As per the title, I would like to run Command & Conquer: Generals in full HD (or at very least a widescreen resolution).

I've tried adding the parameters `-xres 1920 -yres 1080 -quickstart` to the shortcut on my desktop and to the advanced launch options in Origin itself.

Neither of these methods seem to work anymore, the game still loads at the resolution set in the options.ini - changing the resolution there doesn't seem to make any difference either.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: I suppose that you see no option for that ingame? You can try editing the .ini file

Comment: No option in game, and I already tried editing the .ini as per my question, no joy.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's probably too late since you asked. But I know simple solution.

Just download the patch that fixes problems with the game, such as setting the resolution, optimizing the game, repair multiplayer servers (by GameSpy server shutdown).

https://www.gentool.net/

[image: settings resolution]

Resolution settings are possible after installation, in the in-game settings.